# Interlocked ops vs XXX::atomic on Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, atomic, interlocked

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Interlocked winapi functions instead of any library provides atomic operations on Win32 platform?

Portability is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If portability is not a concern then you're basically down to deciding whom you trust more to get this right.  A library is generally designed to provide portability.  It otherwise has a tough time competing with an OS provided implementation that's been battle-hardened for over 15 years.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855671/how-do-i-atomically-swap-2-ints-in-c/3855824#3855824) to see an example of how the obvious implementation is not in fact the best.

Comment: Well, for example, there is TBB::atomic<T> of Intel. Microsoft provides OS, but, Intel produces the processor. Who would you trust more?

Comment: Hehe, do you trust Intel code to run well on an AMD processor?

Comment: Let's assume that the code will always be running on Intel processor which is true in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The Interlocked winapi functions work on old processors even when there is no CPU support for locked operations. 386 and maybe 486, not really a issue today unless you still support Win9x and older NT.

Comment: They work *differently* on those CPUs though. (they're only atomic with respect to other interlocked operations)

Answer (score 0):

It would likely depend up on the specific atomic library in question.

A good library with a specific back-end would likely end up with the same implementation of a couple of ASM instructions to issue an x86 *lock* instruction and do their work.  And assuming the library itself is portable, subsequently make your code portable.

A naive atomic implementation **might** do something heavier like use a mutex to protect a normal variable.  I don't know of any that do - just making the point for argument.

As such, given your stated non-portability requirements, using the Win32 functions should be fine.  Alternately, go ahead with an Atomic version, but perhaps look at the actual implementation.