# Purpose of CMPXCHG instruction without LOCK prefix?

Tags: multithreading, x86, cpu, atomic, compare-and-swap

I am reading Vol 3a of the Intel Developer manuals:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html

and on page 245 it implies only `XCHG` instruction has automatic bus locking. Instructions such as `XADD` and `CMPXCHG` do not automatically lock the system bus and to do so you need to prefix with `LOCK` . To me, this suggests the instructions alone are not atomic across multiple CPU cores.

So what is the purpose of these instructions, if they aren't atomic?

Before I read the manual I expected these instructions would inherently be atomic at the CPU level. I thought that was the reason for combining the "compare" and "set" functions.

EDIT:

The reason could be to enforce atomicity on a single CPU core??

Comment: It supports the holy grail of lockless programming on a processor with a strong memory model.  Covered pretty well by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855824/17034).

Comment: Why does lockless programming not require the LOCK prefix? From your link it seems the instructions are atomic on that CPU, but just not in terms of multiple CPUs/cores?

Comment: See my answer on the linked duplicate, it's answering this exact question.  (Although I'm not sure the original question I posted it under intended to ask that.  Oops :P)

Answer (score 1):

A compiler could optimize a conditional set, e.g.

```
if (n == 42) { n = 2 };
```

into a `CMPXCHG` (without `LOCK` prefix), if that's actually faster.

Furthermore `CMPXCHG` is atomic on a uni-processor system, where you still need to synchronize against interrupts (which can fire *between* any two instructions, but not in the middle of one instruction on the core).

**You can read me about the use-cases for `CMPXCHG` without `LOCK` prefix in [Peter Cordes's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273130/194894)**

Comment: How? This isn't a great example unless you actually show the assembly.

Comment: Interesting point.  Usually branchless code ends up unconditionally writing and old or new value (e.g. load/cmov/store or SIMD load/blend/store).  But I think `cmpxchg` without `lock` really is a conditional store, at least according to the manual.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg.  So it doesn't "invent writes" by introducing a non-atomic read/rewrite in the compare-failed case.  (If it did, that wouldn't be safe if another thread was writing `n` at the same time.  The store could come after another thread's store and step on it.)